# Submit button onClick firing on form load

Tags: javascript

I am creating a JavaScript form on a webpage on the fly.

When the form is created it triggers the onclick event for my submit button (and as a result triggers a validation function that I have created for the form).

How do I prevent the onclick event from firing when the form is created?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
var myForm = document.createElement('form');
myForm.action = 'http://www.urlhere.com';
myForm.method = 'post';

var mySubmit = document.createElement('input');  
mySubmit.id = 'submitButton';  
mySubmit.type = 'Submit';  
mySubmit.value = 'Book Now';  
myForm.appendChild(mySubmit);  
myLayer.appendChild(myForm);
mySubmit.onclick = validateNow();
```

This is the validation function:

```
function validateNow() {
    alert('Validating Form');
}
```

Comment: Does it triggers click event even though, you do not this? Anyway, show at least simplified version of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
mySubmit.onclick = validateNow();
```

Above does not assign the function reference, but runs the validate function. Try this:

```
mySubmit.onclick = validateNow;
```

or this:

```
mySubmit.onclick = function () { 
    validateNow();
};
```